# Data is not passing on to the controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, vue.js, axios

I am getting a problem in passing data to the controller through axios. When I click on the submit button the data doesn't save into database.

```
save(){ 
  axios.post('/phonebook',this.$data.list)
       .then((response) => console.log(response))
            .catch((error) => console.log(error)
       );
}
```

Controller request not received.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $pb = new Phonebook;
    $pb->name = $request->name;
    $pb->phone = $request->phone;
    $pb->email = $request->email;
    $pb->save();

    return $pb;
}
```

Web.php

```
Route::resource('phonebook','PhonebookController');
```

Request should receive and It should store data in the database.

This is my component:

```
<script>
    export default {

        props: ['openmodel'],

        data() {
            return {
                list: {
                    name: '', 
                    phone: '',
                    email: ''
                }
            };
        },

        methods: {
            close() {
                this.$emit('closeRequest');
            }, 
            save() {
                axios.post('/phonebook', this.$data.list)
                    .then((response) => console.log(response))
                    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: We don't know how `this.$data` looks like and what is in there. Also you might want to just print out what your `Request $request` in the php contains. I see `.list` in the post function, while in the php it seems like you are looking for keys: eg `$request->name`. Also do you get to this point? or might the route be wrong?

Comment: Could you share the route and error that you are getting also ?

Comment: try to add `Content-type: application/json` header at axios request

Comment: Try with below route:

Route::post('/phonebook', 'ControllerName@functionName');

Comment: @Luca Angioloni  Here below is what yu looking for.<script>
export default{
 props:['openmodel'],

 data(){
   return{
    list:{
     name:'',
     phone:'',
     email:''
    },
    
   }
  },

 methods:{
     close(){
       this.$emit('closeRequest')
     },
    save(){ 
  axios.post('/phonebook',this.$data.list)
       .then((response) => console.log(response))
            .catch((error) => console.log(error)
       );
}
 }
}
</script>

Comment: do you include your csrf token at the meta tag?

Comment: ZeroOne I havent included csrf token

Comment: @VarunKumar Ok this answers my first question, what about the rest? Everyone is suggesting that it is a routing problem. Do you confirm this? Are you sure that you never get to the point where that php code is executed?

Comment: @Luca Angioloni I am using resource route Route::resource('phonebook','PhonebookController'); I have tried  Route::post('/phonebook', 'PhonebookController@store'). Its stil not working

Comment: @kuncham Vasu I have tried but its not working but when I checked my console I am getting the error like <br />\n<b>Deprecated</b>: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in <b>Unknown</b> on lin

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your support. It works now. I was using php version 5.6. When I updated my Php version to 7. It all works now.